# a counterexample in Muckenhoupt $A_1$ class.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

We say $w$: $\mathbb R^N\to[0,+\infty)$ belons to Muckenhoupt $A_1$ class if there is a constant $C$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{|B|}\int_{B(y)}w(x)dx\leq Cw(y)
$$
for all $y\in \mathbb R^N$ and all balls $B(y)$.

Now given a finite Radon measure $\nu$, I want to construct a strictly positive function $w\in A_1$ but $w\notin L^1(d\nu)$. By $L^1(d\nu)$ I mean function $u$ such that 
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^N}|u|\,d\nu<\infty.
$$
I don't have a good idea on how to get started... Since I only need an example, it is ok to explicitly write down a Radon measure $\nu$ if it makes the construction of example easier.

Thank you very much!

PS: Thanks @tryss for a nice and clear example. I also think would it be possible to prove that for every $\nu\in \mathcal M$, we can prove that there exists a $w$ as described in above question. Here $\mathcal M$ denotes the space of finite Radon measure.

Comment: You mean Radon measure I suppose?

Comment: @Tryss Yea of course! Fixed. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only want an exemple, take

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} u d\nu = \int_0^{\infty} u(x) e^{-x} dx $$

Now take $u(x) = e^x$

$u$ is clearly not in $L^1(d\nu)$

Now for $0 < d < y$

$$\frac{1}{e^{-(y-d)}-e^{-(y+d)}}  \int_{y-d}^{y+d} 1 dx = \frac{2d}{e^{-(y-d)}-e^{-(y+d)}} = e^{y} \frac{2d}{e^d-e^{-d}}$$

And the function $d \mapsto \frac{2d}{e^d-e^{-d}}$ is bounded on $[0,+\infty[$, so you've got the result

Comment: Thank you! This is great. I actually thinking would it be possible to prove that for any $nu\in \mathcal M$, what about the existence of such $w$. It looks interesting, although I don't need it for now...